# How to create a hierarchy in Elasticsearch

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, full-text-search

I am trying to create a nested hierarchy in Elasticsearch by declaring the parentype and childtype in the index. I have a total of 8 indexes which will form the hierarchy, I am trying to search a text from any of 8 indexes forming the hierarchy using java based on the result from elastic search

I see that this would potentially lead to performance related issues based on the data size.

What would be good approach of doing this.

1. Normalize the table --> since there are multiple levels of hierarchy every time I update a record  i need to update all the indexes.
2. Go with parent-child relationship in elastic search --> I see lot there is lot of performance impact in here since I have to search all the indexes and then group all the results and then call again the parent and child based on the the result set.

Comment: `I have a total of 8 indexes which will form the hierarchy` Can you explain this with an example?

Comment: My index will look like country, state, county, school, grades, students. So here student is child of grade, grade is school, school is child of county, county is child of state, state is child of country. IN this case we have total of 6 tables in SQL database and we synch the SQL table to ES in near real time. So I am trying to search any filed from any of the 6 indexes and trying to from a complete hierarchy from country to student.

Comment: I would suggest not to normalize and distribute date into multiple index like in MySql. You should decide based on what type of queries you will executing. Its ok if you duplicate some data across indexes.

Comment: I have read in ES documentation that when we do a search on multiple indexes there would be lot of performance issues and also memory overhead. Is that recommended? And when we do create multiple indexes, can we retrive the hierarchy based on all the result set with in ES?

Comment: I'm not clear on your use case.  What kind of hierarchy you want to derive? What kind of searches you need to perform? After understanding all the use-cases it can be decided on hoe many indexes to keep.